# How to check if a select field has a certain option value without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html-select

How do you check if an option with a particular value exists in a select field?

```
<select>
  <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

If select has value "o1" = true

If select has value "o4" = false

Comment: Get a reference to the select element. It has an options property that is a collection of all its options. For loop through them. Check their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the options and check their values:

```
var select = document.getElementById('selectID') || 
             document.forms[formName or index].elements[selectName or index];
var options = select.options

for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (options[i].value == 'foo') {
    // found option with value 'foo'
  }
}
```

Comment: Might want to add a `break;` at the end of the `if` block? Either way, good answer :) Maybe the use of `querySelector(All)` could be useful too

Answer (score 1):

If you'll add an `id` field to the select, say `id="selector"` you can do:

```
var x = document.getElementById("selector").options;
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    if (x[i].value == "o1"){
    ...
```

etc.

Comment: The OP says nothing about checking its `selected` state

Comment: No problem. Well now you might want to show looping instead of hardcoding `[0]` (even though you have "etc.")